# Laravel 5.4-Vue npm run watch error

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, vue.js

I am trying to execute `npm run watch` from the Windows Command Line in my Laravel-Vue Project. I am using the following:

1. Windows 10 Home Edition
2. Node Version 7.10.0
3. npm version 5.5.1

Here is my
**package.json:**

```
    {
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "watchify": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^2.0.0",
    "coffee-script": "^1.8.0",
    "coffeeify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-clean-css": "*",
    "stringify": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "watchify -v -t coffeeify -t stringify resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/js/bundle.js",
    "build": "browserify -v -t coffeeify -t stringify resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/js/bundle.js"
  }
}
```

Whenever I run the command, I am getting the following error:

```
> @ watch C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue
> watchify -v -t coffeeify -t stringify resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/js/bundle.js

path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:695:5)
    at Deps.lookupPackage (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:452:29)
    at Deps._transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:93:10)
    at Deps.Transform._read (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at Deps.Transform._write (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at Labeled.Pipeline._write (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\stream-splicer\index.js:73:22)
    at doWrite (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:279:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:266:5)
    at Labeled.Writable.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:211:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `watchify -v -t coffeeify -t stringify resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/js/bundle.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Debarun Pal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-09T10_17_15_209Z-debug.log
```

**Debug Log Dump**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'cache',
1 verbose cli   'clean' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v7.10.0
4 verbose npm-session 1bde4f10d2ea77e8
5 verbose stack Error: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
5 verbose stack
5 verbose stack If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
5 verbose stack     at clean (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:70:22)
5 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.cache (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:45:16)
5 verbose stack     at Object.commandCache.(anonymous function) (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:149:13)
5 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:84:30)
5 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
5 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
6 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\software_vue
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clean"
9 verbose node v7.10.0
10 verbose npm  v5.5.1
11 error As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
11 error
11 error If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am unable to trace back to the issue and kind of lost, rather, where to start debugging.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/40 Hope this helps